# xorg crashes when firefox starts

Tags: debian, xorg, firefox, backports

When I log in and start Firefox, my computer crashes. I get back to the lightdm login screen. When I log in for the second time, Firefox runs with no problem.

This is what Firefox prints to stderr:

`firefox-esr: Fatal IO error 17 (File exists) on X server :0.`

I am using Debian Jessie, I started having this problem after I upgraded a couple of packages from the jessie-backports repo.

Comment: Please check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` for clues.

Comment: The end of the `.old` file said X terminated with Segmentation Fault and gave a backtrace. I don't know what to do with this information. The files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7yio03o1vvgjat/Xorg.0.log.old?dl=1 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebzd7g3b9wi0h19/Xorg.0.log?dl=1

Comment: It's clearly a bug, probably in a package you pulled from jessie-backports recently. Was the noveau driver amongst them? Check `/var/log/apt/history.log` if you can't recall exactly. Try downgrading each to the previous version, and submit a bug report (use `reportbug`) for the one causing the problem. Attach these logs, and note that the one with the segfault has `removing GPU device` and `NOUVEAU(G0): NVLeaveVT is called.`. Also check if your `kern.log` contains something interesting at the time (kernel timestamp `[     6.164]`, but consider that these restart at each reboot).

Comment: Here is a list of software I upgraded that day: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcr7lhh78ylqaym/apt%20log.txt?dl=0. Nouveau is not one of them. I will start downgrading them when I have more time.

Comment: I need software from the backports repo because some of my hardware is incompatible with the software in the stable version.

Comment: The `kern.log` file is just empty

Comment: Your `kern.log` was probably rotated, check `kern.log.1` (or `kern.log.2.gz` and so on) instead.

Comment: After a quick look nothing stands out for me in your list of upgraded packages. I'd start by downgrading _systemd_ and _udev_, for those can have pretty broad effects on overall system behavior.

Comment: Turns out the `kern.log` file wasn't really empty, it was read protected, and vim just opened an empty buffer instead. It didn't contain information at that timestamp anyway.

Comment: Firefox stopped triggering the bug (after I changed my computer's hostname). I didn't upgrade or downgrade anything so I don't really think it was fixed, but I haven't been able to reproduce it for a week now.

Comment: Köszi a segítséget